# PTIJ: Why do we need a verse that we follow the majority?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Gemara ([Chulin 11a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.11a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) has a long debate trying to prove that we follow the majority.

Why do we need those verses? We killed the 10 sons of Haman, and the only way we know that they were his sons was because "most of the time, a wife's children are the husbands".

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Which verses in the Gemara?

Answer (score 5):

The [Chida](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21838&st=&pgnum=143) said that someone answered (by "the Purim meal") that the tree on which Haman and his sons were hung was 50 cubits tall, parallel to Noach's ark which was also 50 cubits, so the two had similar properties.

One of the properties of Noach's ark was that it only let in those animals which didn't sin, so presumably would Haman's pole not accept Mamzeirim. So there's no source from Haman that we go after the majority, as the pole made sure that the ten sons of Haman were really his sons.